# Can I checkout multiple repos all at once, or in parallel in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

We have a site builder that is made of many modules. We do not use a monorepo. We use many repos for this purpose and each repo has a module in it (a logical module, not a git module).

For example, this is a list of some of our modules:

```
Accounts
Blog
Clients
Configuration
Contacts
Courses
Discounts
Galleries
...
```

So, when we want to run a GitHub Action, we first need to get many repos. For example 20 different repos.

We're using `actions/checkout@v3`. This is an example of our `build.yml` file:

```
      - name: Get Modules/Blog
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: Modules/Blog
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          path: Modules/Blog

      - name: Get Modules/Configuration
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: Modules/Configuration
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          path: Modules/Configuration

      - name: Get Modules/Contacts
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: Modules/Contacts
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          path: Modules/Contacts
```

But this is not efficient. It takes more time (maybe near 20 extra seconds) and it leaves a lot of logs in our actions which makes debugging them harder.

Is there a way for us to somehow get all of our modules in one step?

Comment: You can write your own custom script for this to clone all those repos in parallel as `actions/checkout` doesn't seem to support such a feature.